# HttpHandler to render a png from an array of bytes

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, content-type, httphandler

Okay, this should be simple, but I just can't get it to work. I have an array of bytes, read from a png file. I'm trying to write a (very) simple HttpHandler to render the image:

```
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "image/png")
context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
context.Response.End()
```

When I open the page in a browser, I just get gibberish,

> �PNG  IHDR���X��sRGB���gAMA�� �a pHYs���o�d`  ...

It's obviously something with the header information I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try calling `context.Response.Flush()` before `.End()`? Also, what are you using to achieve this? Aspx page, web service, mvc action?

Comment: Fixed it, turned out to be just a browser issue. Restarting IE certainly helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `ContentType` property instead of `AddHeader`:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
...
```

Two more diagnostics:

- If you use "save" in the browser and save it to a png file, does that render properly?
- Use [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) to see what's really coming back in the response (which exact bytes etc)

Comment: Or maybe [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) before wireshark, for more friendly debugging ;).

Comment: @ppiotrowicz: I personally tend to go straight to Wireshark to avoid any proxy-related changes to what's going on. Matter of personal preference though :)

Comment: Got it working now, it seems it was just my browser refusing reload the image, regardless of much I hit it with CTRL-F5. But I'll defininately look into Wireshark, thanks for the pointer.